# Best practice to apply error class to element using angular and bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently performing an ajax call and if an error is returned, I'd like to apply an error class to an element. What's the best/optimal/easiest way to perform this?

Answer (score 2):

If the element and the Ajax call are part of the same controller/directive, simply update your scope. For instance

```
ajax().error(function(e) {
  $scope.error = true;
});
```

And in the HTML, the element will get the class "something-is-wrong"

```
<div ng-class="{'something-is-wrong': error}"> ... </div>
```

---

Now if you also want to display the error message, intead of a boolean you could put the messahe inside scope.error

```
ajax().error(function(e) {
  // Or just $scope.error = "Cannot do stuff"
  $scope.error = formatMessage(e);
});
```

html:

```
<div ng-class="{'something-is-wrong': error}"> {{error}} </div>
```

---

Finally, if the ajax call is not in the same environment than your element, you could rely on a service.

```
module.factory('errorService', function() {
  return { error: null };
});

ajax().error(function(e) {
  errorService.error = e;
});
```

Html (after adding errorService to your scope):

```
<div ng-class="{'something-is-wrong': errorService.error}"> ... </div>
```